# Unable to get the selected picklist value in VF page

Tags: visualforce, picklist, rerender, dependent-picklist

We have a web2case form (Screen shot attached below) and In the form we need to show/Hide loa reason field based on the values in Category and sub- category picklist fields, This functionality is not working. 
on our analysis we found that the VF Page is not getting the selected value for Category and sub- category  fields hence the rendering issue.

Can anyone help me in this regard.

```
    <div class="page-header">
        <h4>Web Entry Form</h4>
    </div>
    <apex:messages styleClass="alert alert-danger" />
    <apex:form id="theForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" html-role="form">


        <div class="well well-sm"><strong>Case Information</strong></div>
        <div>
            <apex:outputLabel value="Category" for="Category" styleClass="control-label"></apex:outputLabel>
            <span class="text-danger">*</span>
            <apex:inputField label="Category" value="{!caseDet.Category__c}" required="true" styleClass="form-control"/> 
            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div> 
        </div>
        <div class="form-group form-group-sm">                
            <apex:outputLabel value="Sub Category" for="SubCategory" styleClass="control-label" ></apex:outputLabel>
            <span class="text-danger">*</span>


                <apex:inputField value="{!caseDet.Sub_Category__c}" required="true" styleClass="form-control" /> 
                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="panelCH1" />


            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>              
        </div>

        <apex:outputPanel id="panelCH1">
            <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!IF(caseDet.Sub_Category__c =='LOA',true,false)}">
                <div class="form-group form-group-sm">                
                    <apex:outputLabel value="LOA Reason" for="lOaRSN1" styleClass="control-label"></apex:outputLabel>                    
                    <span class="text-danger">*</span>
                    <apex:inputField id="loa" value="{!caseDet.LOA_Reason__c}" styleClass="form-control"/>

                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>              
                </div>
            </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:outputPanel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by mistake i closed the input tag before the action support and hence the issue